# undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass problem with simple_form form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

simple_form creates a problem:

[image: screenshot errors]

I'll explain what I did: i've 2 scaffold:

questions/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@question ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <%= render "info_users" %>

      <%= f.input :question, label: "Quelle est votre question ou votre suggestion ?", input_html: { class: "textarea "}, wrapper: false, label_html: {class: "label"}, placeholder: "Commencez vos Questions par << Comment >>, << Pourquoi>>, << Que >>, etc...", autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.button :submit,'Ajouter Une Question', class: "button is-info is-rounded " %>
<% end %>
```

courses/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@course) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>    
  # here go all inputs
  <%= f.button :submit," Créer le Cours" ,class: "button is-info is-large is-rounded" %>
<% end %>
```

Now I use these two forms in my home view and that's when simple_form becomes a problem. Here is the call code of the partials in home/_feed.html.erb

Note: I created a partial _feed.html.erb in home to render it in index.html.erb

home/_feed.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <article class="media box">
    <div class="media-content">
      <%= render :partial => "questions/form" %>
    </div>
    <div class="media-content">
      <%= render :partial => "courses/form" %>
    </div>
  </article>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you define `@question` .. The error is from this, it is not defined or it is set to `nil`. Check your controller action,

Comment: Can you post controller code? It will be helpful in understanding why `@question` is set to `nil`.

Comment: That is a ton of noise. Please prune your post to the pertinent details because there is an awful amount of information that has nothing to do with your issue as it stands right now

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't set the new question in `QuestionsController`

```
def new
  @question = Question.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no defined `@question` and `@course` for forms, because now you render them from HomeController#index. Also, it is bad idea to use instance variables in partials, because it is hard to say, where from they come to the partial. Use only local variables and pass them to the partial

```
# questions/_form.html.erb    
<%= simple_form_for(question) do |f| %>
  # form code goes here
<% end %>

# the same for courses/_form.html.erb, change @course to course

# home/_feed.html.erb    
<%= render partial: "questions/form", question: @question %>
<%= render partial: "courses/form", course: @course %>
```

Define instance variables in home_controller.rb

```
def index
  @question = current_user.questions.new # I suppose you want to create associated records
  @course = current_user.courses.new
end
```